# How to use new androidx.media2.widget.VideoView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack, androidx

### Problem

Not able to find information about `androidx.media2.VideoView`.
I want to stream a video from an url which is working with `VideoView1`, however I can't achieve it with`VideoView2`.

### My Research

In the documentation they describe this method:

`setVideoUri`
open fun `setVideoUri(uri: Uri!, headers: MutableMap<String!, String!>?): Unit`
Sets video URI using specific headers.

However this method seems to be no longer available (I am  using `mediaWidgetVersion 1.0.0-alpha06`)

Comment: I can't test this right now, but, looking at the source, it seems that now you would use the `VideoView#setMediaItem()` method instead, and you can construct an appropriate `MediaItem` with the `androidx.media2.UriMediaItem.Builder` class. It has a constructor that takes a `Context` and a `Uri`, and one that takes those along with that headers `Map` and a `List<HttpCookie>`, both of which are optional (`@Nullable`).

Comment: Just got a chance to test this, and it's confirmed. Simply replace the `setVideoUri(Uri, ?)` call with a call to `setMediaItem(MediaItem)`, where the `MediaItem` is constructed with an `androidx.media2.UriMediaItem.Builder`.

Answer (score 4):

For future references **androidx.media2.widget.VideoView**'s simple usage is:

> 1. Create **MediaMetadata** if required. Here I'm simply setting media title

```
  val mediaMetaData = MediaMetadata.Builder()
      .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "media title")
      .build()
```

> 2. Create **MediaItem** from any sources. Here I'm using url as a source

```
  val mediaItem = UriMediaItem.Builder(videoUrl.toUri())
      .setMetadata(mediaMetaData) // optional
      .build()
```

> 3. Create **SessionPlayer** and set it to **VideoView** by calling `setPlayer`

```
  val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer(this)
  with(mediaPlayer) {
    videoView.setPlayer(this)

    setMediaItem(mediaItem)
    // play when ready
    prepare().addListener(
      Runnable { play() },
      Executors.BACKGROUND_EXECUTOR
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use MediaItem internal builder like this to create a UriMediaItem

```java
UriMediaItem yourUriMediaItemHere = new UriMediaItem.Builder(context, uri).build();
```

and then use videoViews setMediaItem method like this

```java
videoView.setMediaItem(yourUriMediaItemHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this document:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media2/widget/VideoView

> Using VideoView with SessionPlayer or MediaController
> For simple use cases that do not require communication with a MediaSession, apps need to create a player instance that extends SessionPlayer (e.g. MediaPlayer) and link it to this view by calling setPlayer(SessionPlayer).
> For more advanced use cases that require a MediaSession (e.g. handling media key events, integrating with other MediaSession apps as Assistant), apps need to create a MediaController that's attached to the MediaSession and link it to this view by calling setMediaController(MediaController).

But there's one very important thing which didn't get noted from this document.

Here's the code snippet about how to use this new `VideoView`.

```
MediaMetadata mediaMetaData = new MediaMetadata.Builder()
        .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, url)
        .build();

UriMediaItem mediaItem = new UriMediaItem.Builder(Uri.parse(url)).build();
mediaItem.setMetadata(mediaMetaData);

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(getActivity());
mediaPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
mediaPlayer.prepare();

videoView.setPlayer(mediaPlayer);
```

You have to call `mediaPlayer.prepare()` to tell the `MediaPlayer` to start loading.
Otherwise you'll get `IllegalStateException` with useless messages.